# Printing API data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I'm new to React and have a 2 part question:

1. I'm trying to print data from an API in React using the following code but I am not getting any output. What's the issue?
2. After the Category and Question prints, I want the answer to be hidden. It must only be revealed when the button is clicked. How do I achieve this?

   ```
    class Question extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            category: [],
            question: [],
            answer: [],
            revealed: [false]
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios({
          url: "http://jservice.io/api/random?count=1",
          method: "GET"
        })
        .then((result) => {
          this.setState({
            category: result.category,
            question: result.question,
            answer: result.answer
          });
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { category } = this.state;
        const { question } = this.state;
        const { answer } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    {category}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {question}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {answer}
                </div>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.answer.setState(true)}>Reveal answer</button>
            </div>
        );
    }}export default Question;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This code needs a lot of refactoring.

This will definitely do it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Question = () => {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState();
  const [category, setCategory] = useState({ title: 'default title' });
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState();
  const [showAnswer, setShowAnswer] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      url: 'http://jservice.io/api/random?count=1',
      method: 'GET',
    }).then((result) => {
      setQuestion(result[0].question);
      setAnswer(result[0].answer);
      setCategory(result[0].category);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Category: {category.title}</div>
      <div>Question: {question}</div>
      <div>Answer: {showAnswer ? answer : null}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setShowAnswer(true)}>Reveal Answer</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Question;
```

In the above i used useEffect for lifecycle events like componentDidMount and useState hook for managing state in this functional component.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to update `revealed`  and then you can pass by props `revealed`  to create the ternary  `{revealed ? answer : ""}`

If this is a project of yours, I would recommed to start using ReactJS with hooks!

```
class Question extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             category: [],
             question: [],
             answer: [],
             revealed: false
         };
         // Binding this keyword 
         this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this) 
     }

updateState(){ 
    // Changing state 
    this.setState({
      revealed: true,
    }) 
  } 

 componentDidMount() {
     axios({
       url: "http://jservice.io/api/random?count=1",
       method: "GET"
     })
     .then((result) => {
       this.setState({
         category: result.category,
         question: result.question,
         answer: result.answer
       });
     });
 }

 render() {
     const { category, question, answer, revealed   } = this.state;

     return(
         <div>
             <div>
                 {category}
             </div>
             <div>
                 {question}
             </div>
             <div>
                 {revealed ? answer : ""}
             </div>
             <button type="button" onClick={this.updateState}>Reveal answer</button>
         </div>
     );
 }}
export default Question;
```